# Trying to find max resolution for AMD card

Tags: display, graphics-card, resolution, amd-radeon, high-resolution

I am attempting to buy a large monitor for my younger brother for Christmas. I want to be sure his computer is *able to support resolution beyond 1920x1080*. He has an **AMD A6-3650 APU** with **Radeon HD 6530D**. I have been searching for the maximum resolution for this card for an hour now and found nothing. [AMD's page](http://shop.amd.com/us/All/Detail/Processor/AD3650WNGXBOX#Details) for this card is extremely lacking in detail compared to other AMD card pages. Other sites give almost all other details, but neglect the maximum resolution. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You need to specify the motherboard and the port too (DVI, HDMI, DP, etc). For example the specifications for the [Gigabyte GA-A75-D3H motherboard](http://www.gigabyte.eu/products/product-page.aspx?pid=3929#sp) say this about the onboard graphics: "1 x **DVI-D port**, supporting a maximum resolution of **2560x1600**; 1 x **HDMI port**, supporting a maximum resolution of **1920x1200**".

Answer (score 3):

You’re right, not only do they not specify details in that page, they don’t even give specifications in the [*video-card* pages](http://shop.amd.com/us/All/Search?SearchFacets=category:Graphic%20Card;model:Radeon%20HD%206350) either (I guess for some reason, AMD just doesn’t think users need to know that stuff `¬_¬`). Curiously, resolution information is not specified in comparison charts for the [AMD cards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_AMD_graphics_processing_units#Northern_Islands_.28HD_6xxx.29_Series), nor even for the [series-specific charts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northern_Islands_%28GPU_family%29).

Nontheless, fortunately, specifications are not difficult to find. Google `6530D resolution` to get [this page](http://www.game-debate.com/hardware/?gid=489&graphics=Radeon%20HD%206530D) (figure 1). Even better, the answer is right there in the [search results](http://www.google.com/search?q=6530D%20resolution) (figure 2).

That card supports different resolutions depending on what mode the output is and what cable is being used (figure 3):

- The maximum *digital* resolution (using a DVI or HDMI cable) is 2560×1600<sup>**1**</sup>
- The maximum *analog* resolution (when using a VGA cable)  is 2048×1536

<sup>**1**</sup>Note, that to actually achieve a resolution of 2560×1600 with a [DVI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dvi) cable, you must use a *Dual-Link* cable, either integrated (-I) or digital only (-D) will work, as long as it doesn’t have that gap in the middle of the pins.

---

**Figure 1**: Game Debate analysis of HD 6530D

[image: Screenshot of the page with the resolution highlighted]

**Figure 2**: Google results with max res in page summary

[image: Screenshot of Google results with maximum resolution mentioned in page summary]

**Figure 3**: Common video cables (VGA, DVI(-D), HDMI)

[image: Photos of VGA, DVI(-D), and HDMI cables]

**Figure 4**: Different types of DVI cables:

[image: Diagram of DVI connector variants]